# @Styles.Reder y @Scripts.Render no son reconocidos en asp.net MVC 5!

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Asp.net C# con MVC 5, y al momento de llamar a los estilos y a los js en el Layout, extrañamente no los reconoce, ¿Porque sera?

Me sale el siguiente mensaje: el nombre 'Styles' no existe en el contexto actual.

Lo mismo al llamar los scripts: el nombre 'Scripts' no existe en el contexto actual.

Tengo todo agregado, tanto en el web.config de la Views como la Bundle Config

Comment: En el webconfig de las vistas, en los namespace está está línea <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>?

Comment: podrias poner el codigo de como defines el bundler en el layout? valida que en el bundle config define la misma url